# Finding a 'Number'

Tags: c++, counter

In my code I'm trying to find "numbers", "identifiers", and "words". Numbers are defined as sequences of numbers that are separated by a letter , non-letter, or a non digit character( such as a space or /n).

Such as:
**898A111** (This has two numbers)
**898 111** (This also has two numbers)

**Words** are defined as a letter leading a sequence of numbers, letters, or both.

Such as:
**AJKALJ8923 or ALSJOIA or B93082092** (These are all considered words)

And Identifiers are the letters used to lead a word, or separate two numbers

Such as:

**898A111** (The Identifier is A)
**AJLKAKA** (The Identifier is A)

I've been trying to scribble out possible solutions, and as far as checking words I believe I have a solution, but as far as counting and identifying both "numbers" and "identifiers" (in a string), I'm at a complete loss. Anyone have any ideas? Any help at all would be appreciated. I'd say my knowledge of C++ is at a beginner's level.

Main function:http://pastebin.com/MrXKLXYv
Header file: http://pastebin.com/Xn23zn7X 
Assignment for reference if I was unclear: http://pastebin.com/2bgEPqbG

Comment: you don't really use if statement for all letters.

Comment: An alternative to using if statements for each letter would be `alphabet[letter-'a']++;`

Comment: @Lalaland but with a range check before: `if(input.at(i) >= 'a' && input.at(i) <= 'z') alphabet[letter-'a']++;`.

Comment: Also, don't forget that you can use loops to print all of your letters. `for (int whichLetter = 0; whichLetter<26; whichLetter++) { char letter = 'a'+whichLetter; // etc}`. PS You can also iterate directly over the characters : `for (char letter = 'a';  letter <= 'z'; letter++) { //etc } `.

Comment: If you have a state such as "currentlyInANumber" then you should be able to get the identifiers in numbers by simply checking if the current character is a letter and you are currently in a number.

Comment: Check the first letter to see what type it is, a alpha or a digit. Then handle this two situations respectively. When finding numbers, `if (input.at[i] >= '0' && input.at[i] <= '9')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *regex* to match the format you want. But as you are using C++, you must download Boost first, and include the head file "boost/regex.hpp"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `std::bitset` to handle this situation.

```
#include <bitset>

std::string strInput = "898A111";
std::string strDigit = "0123456789";
std::bitset<255> bsDigit;
std::vector<std::string> vctDigit;
for (int i = 0; i < strDigit.length(); i++)
{
    bsDigit[strDigit.at(i)] = true;
}

int nTemp = 0;
int nLength = strInput.length();
for (int i = 0; i < nLength; i++)
{
    if (!bsDigit[strInput.at(i)])
    {
        vctDigit.push_back(strInput.substr(nTemp, i - nTemp));
        nTemp = i + 1;
    }
    else if (i == nLength - 1)
    {
        vctDigit.push_back(strInput.substr(nTemp, (i + 1) - nTemp));
    }
}

std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = vctDigit.begin();
for (; it != vctDigit.end(); it++)
{
    std::cout << (*it).c_str() << std::endl;
}
```